# How to set and read cookie of the website so the website display with different language

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am currently writing a website that display by different language by this code:

> ```
>    var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; 
>    if (userLang.substring(0, 2) == "zh") {
>        location.href = "index_ch.html";
>    }
> ```

But using this javascript has a drawback which is when my browser is in English, I would not be able to manually make it display in Chinese and vice versa. I just want to know how to:

1. Check if a cookie exist
2. If not, run the javascript that I wrote and display in whatever language
3. If not, create a cookie and allow language switching based on it

Thank you

Comment: You should use server-side code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

```
// Test if localStorage is supported by the user's browser
var storageAllowed = typeof(Storage) !== "undefined";

if (storageAllowed) {
  // get cookie
  var userLangCodeCookie = localStorage.getItem("userLangCode");
  // Redirect if exists and not falsy
  if (userLangCodeCookie) {
    location.href = "index_" + userLangCodeCookie + ".html";
  }
}

var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
var userLangCode = userLang.substring(0, 2);

if (userLangCode == "zh") {
  if (storageAllowed) {
    // Set cookie
    localStorage.setItem("userLangCode", 'ch');
  }
  location.href = "index_ch.html";
}
```